# AWK: Apply filter only if field separator is present

Tags: awk

I surprisingly found that when you do this:

> echo "hello" | awk -F'|' '{print $1;}'

you get:

> hello

How to return nothing given that the field separator '|' is absent in the line ?

I do this to extract dates in beginning of log lines, but some lines don't start with a date and then give me this problem. Thanks, I am quite new in awk.

Comment: This may be an example of [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Edit your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
echo "hello" | awk -F'|' 'NF>1 {print $1}'

echo "hello|1" | awk -F'|' 'NF>1 {print $1}'
hello
```

Only when you have more than one field, return the first field

On a file

```
cat testing
record1|val1
record2|val2
record3
record4|val4

awk -F'|' 'NF>1 {print $1}' testing
record1
record2
record4
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use

```
awk -F'|' '$1==$0'
```

If no separator is present, then field one will contain the whole line.